# Get certain part of query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I got different query strings, for example:

```
?key=ad27gdahd3a2s1be87adgw8he2
?key=829d3a5s1bh98dh298hd2jh3jsd
```

If you look closer, each `string` does contain some equal values:

- ?key=ad27gdah`d3a`2`s1b`e87adgw8he2
- ?key=829`d3a`5`s1b`h98dh298hd2jh3jsd

How can I get the value between `d2a` and `s1b`, in these examples the values `2` and `5`?

I know that I can use [this `geturlparameter` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js) to get the string, but how can I split it at the necessary points?

Comment: do you know the same substrings?

Comment: Does they always the same strings?

Comment: It will always be for example `d3a` and `s1b`.

Comment: then you can use regex `string.match(/d3a(.*)s1b/)[1];`